# What would the equivalent of the Dehn's Invariant of higher dimensions be?

Tags: geometry

Dehn's invariant in $\Bbb R^3$ is constructed by taking the tensor product of the edge lengths and the dihedral angles at each edge and govens what polyhedra are equidecomposable. I assume that this invariant is dimension specific and for higher dimensions, for say $\Bbb R^4$ you could find the tensor product of the 1D faces and 2D dihedral angles and the 2D faces and its dihedral angles between the 3D faces. Giving you two invariants for $\Bbb R^4$ and I would assume $n-2$ invariants for $\Bbb R^n$.

Is this correct? Does it even make sense to take the dihedral angles between 3D faces in $\Bbb R^4$. Would this mean that for two polyhedra, of dimension n, they would need held equal invariants at every level for them to be equidecomposable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Dehn_invariant) states "For higher dimensions there is a generalization, called the Hadwiger invariant or Dehn–Hadwiger invariant. This has given results in dimension four, [a4], and for the case when the group consists of translations only, [a2]" and gives references

[a2]    C.H. Sah, "Hilbert's third problem: scissors congruence" , Pitman (1979)

[a4]    B. Jessen, "Zur Algebra der Polytope" Göttinger Nachrichte Math. Phys. (1972) pp. 47–53

Comment: thanks i know what to seach for now